# IP Resource Errors While Building a Windows Failover Cluster on Azure

Tags: failover, azure, failovercluster

I have setup a failover cluster in Microsoft Azure on four VMs. I have two nodes in one subnet/region, one node in another subnet/region and a final node in a third subnet/region. The cluster passed the validation wizard and was successfully built, but the two nodes in other subnets will not go online, reporting "Failed to bring the resource 'IP Address x.x.x.x' online".

[image: Image of Cluster]

**Azure Vnet Setup**

- Vnet 1 - South Central US - 10.16.16.0/16 - Nodes 1 & 2 - Online
- Vnet 2 - West US - 10.116.16.0/16 - Node 3 - Offline
- Vnet 3 - East US - 10.216.16.0/16 - Node 4 - Offline

All three IP Address resources are DHCP. I've attempted to make them static but they still failed while coming online. If I click "Information Details" on the error I get:

*Error code: 0x80071397*

*The operation failed because either the specified cluster node is not the owner of the resource, or the node is not a possible owner of the resource.*

It seems to be an issue with the way Azure DHCP works, but I'm stalled. There must be a way to get his working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

only one can be online at a time. if you go to the list of nodes, and turn off the node where its ip is the one being used by the cluster (10.16.16), then another ip address in your list will come online.